# How do I call the function with a parameter I set up in firebase functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I've deployed this code to my firebase functions project:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
admin.initializeApp()

export const getEmail = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var from = request.body.sender;
    admin.auth().getUserByEmail(from)
    .then(snapshot => {
        const data = snapshot.toJSON()
        response.send(data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        //Handle error
        console.log(error)
        response.status(500).send(error)
    })
})
```

Which takes in a email parameter that it gets from the user's input on my app. My app's code looks like this:

```
Functions.functions().httpsCallable("https://us-central1-projectname.cloudfunctions.net/getEmail").call(email) { (result, error) in
                if let error = error as NSError? {
                    if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
                        //email isnt taken
                        let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
                        let message = error.localizedDescription
                        let details = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]
                        print(code, message, details)
                    }
                    // ...
                }
                if let text = (result?.data as? [String: Any])?["text"] as? String {
                    // email taken
                }
            }
```

When I run the app and when that function is called, it seems to do nothing, no error message is shown and no data has been sent back. What am I missing?

Update: I went to the logs and nothing has happened in there as if the function was never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually mixing up [HTTP Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?authuser=0) and [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?authuser=0):

You Cloud Function code corresponds to an HTTP one but the code in your front-end seems to call a Callable one.

You should adapt one or the other, most probably adapt your Cloud Function to a Callable one, along the following lines:

```
exports.getEmail = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const from = data.sender;

  return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(from)
  .then(userRecord => {
        const userData = userRecord.toJSON();
        return { userData: userData };
  })
});
```

Have a look at the doc for more details, in particular how to handle errors. The doc is quite detailed and very clear.

Comment: See the update. Also, have a look at the doc for more details, it is quite detailed and very clear.

Comment: I tired the new code and I got an error on the line where it has 'const data = snapshot.toJSON()' saying: 'Shadowed name: 'data''

Comment: Try `const userData = snapshot.toJSON()
            return { userData: userData };`